Orientation of floating tetrahedron
What would be the stable floating orientation of a regular solid tetrahedron with a density close to the liquid, let's say 3/4?
Would it float with a vertex up or with a triangle base up?

What do you think?

The relevant concept is the metacenter

I would vote to reopen this question if it was more conceptual.  The specific theory answer can be found in a memorable paper by Paul Erdös, G, Schibler, and R. Herndon (Am. J. Phys. 60 (1992) 345–356): "Floating equilibrium of symmetrical objects and the breaking of symmetry. Part 2: The cube, the octahedron, and the tetrahedron". If $r$ is the solid/liquid mass density ratio, then the tetrahedron should float corner-up if $r<0.48176$, edge-up if $r>0.51824$, and with one edge vertical for $0.48176<r<0.51824$.

Welcome Claudijo to Physics Stackexchange. If you do edit the question to try to get it reopened, you might want to reference the closely related "Which direction a wooden cube would float in water?" which was also closed as being "Homework-like". You might want to ask how one generally analyzes the stability of floating regular geometric solids. The approach followed by Erdös and his collaborators uses energy minimization.

Thanks @DavidBailey for the pointer and for taking the time to answering the question in you comment.
